# Looking for economics research article that applies concepts from real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, economics

As a final project for my real analysis/advanced calculus I am being asked to write a discussion/critique of a paper in my field that applies concepts from real analysis. This could include anything ranging from convergence and continuity theorems, to numerical methods and the calculus of variation. I'd appreciate any recommendations on specific research or authors to look into.

Thanks!

Comment: This one may be interesting: [Partial differential equation models in macroeconomics](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24505843) *"The purpose of this article is to get mathematicians interested in studying a number of partial differential equations (PDEs) that naturally arise in macroeconomics. These PDEs come from models designed to study some of the most important questions in economics."*

Comment: You could also look for articles about the [Black-Scholes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation).

Answer (score 1):

You might try Paul Romer's article on Mathiness. Not only is he the most recent Nobel Prize winner in economics, but the article is about whether a particular limit exists. 
https://paulromer.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Mathiness.pdf

https://paulromer.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Mathiness-Appendix-Expanded.pdf

Comment: Hello, the first link you posted is a PDF file with five blank pages.

Comment: The best article is the blank article. Because it's the article that one has to create :)

Comment: sorry! try this:  https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.p20151066